# How to validate a JSON schema $ref to another file

Tags: python, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

how can I validate a dictionary using a JSON schema that contain a reference and this reference is in the local file or external files?
I notice that i should use `refresolver` but I don't know how. Please help me to write this code

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "ReferenceToLocalSchema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/LocalType"
        },
        "ReferenceToExternalSchema": {
            "$ref": "Common.json#/definitions/ExternalType"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "LocalType": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "no-write": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `Common.json`

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "definitions": {
        "ExternalType": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "src": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "src"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What tool/library are you using to validate the schema? The validator of your choice should be able to automatically resolve the `$ref` as long as the ref value follows [the spec](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#ref)

Comment: By googling the "refresolver" I've found that you probably use the Python. In that case  you can foound an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159346/jsonschema-refresolver-to-resolve-multiple-refs-in-python